# Upload custom trinket firmware

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader, adafruit, firmware

I'd like to disable the trinket 10-second bootloader when powered up, so it will just begin running the program. I would still like to be able to press the reset button to re-program it.

I found an edited version of the bootloader [here](https://github.com/beargun/Adafruit-Trinket-Gemma-Bootloader). Currently, I am using an Arduino Uno and the 'repair the bootloader' [sketch](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-trinket/repairing-bootloader) to load the hex to the trinket. The default hex is hard coded in the `images.cpp` file and the same hex is included in the Adafruit bootloader GitHub as `trinketgemma_v1.hex`.

How can I compile the forked copy to get the final compiled hex that can be burnt into the trinket?

**Update:**

I get this error when I upload to the board, how did you flash yours?

```
Setting fuses  Set Low Fuse to: F1 -> A000  Set High Fuse to: D5 -> A800  Set Ext Fuse to: 6 -> A400
Verifying fuses...
    Low Fuse: 0xF1 is 0xF1
    High Fuse: 0xD5 is 0xD5
    Ext Fuse: 0x6 is 0x6


Setting fuses


Verifying flash...
verification error at address 0x14C0 Should be 0x33 not 0x5F
Failed to verify chip
```

The fuses are set correctly, but it cannot verify the flash. The supplied Adafruit hex looks like about 93 lines of:

```
":2000000093CA15C0EBCA13C012C011C010C00FC00EC00DC00CC00BC00AC009C008C0112422\n"
```

Where the updated, compiled hex is about 181 lines of:

```
":100000005FCA5FCA5FCA5FCA5FCA5FCA5FCA5FCAA8\n"
```

Does the length of each line matter? The output of a successful flash looks like:

```
Verifying fuses...
    Low Fuse: 0xF1 is 0xF1
    High Fuse: 0xD5 is 0xD5
    Ext Fuse: 0x6 is 0x6


Setting fuses

Verifying flash...
    Flash verified correctly!
Verifying fuses...

Fuses verified correctly!
*OK!*
```

Comment: Looks like you can just replace the hex in the images.cpp, with the hex in `flash_me_xv.hex`. Though you have to encapsulate every line between a `"` and `\n"`. Also make sure to change the fuses in image.cpp (correct value can be found [here](https://github.com/beargun/Adafruit-Trinket-Gemma-Bootloader/blob/master/Makefile#L41-L43)) (PS nice to see someone using my code)

Comment: @Gerben I tried just replacing the hex, however, it says there is an error verifying the flash. I updated the post with more info.

Comment: I used the makefile to upload the boot loader.